# Microsoft SQL Server Express on Windows 8 - Connects but then "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed"

Tags: sql, windows, asp-classic, sql-server-express

I had a flash application my machine set up using SQL Server 2008 Express on Win 7 happily writing to and from a DB using classic asp. Machine crashes,, 1 new hard drive later, and an upgrade to WIN 8 and SQL Server 2012 Express, and the problems appear.

The connection string works fine (and I can use the UID and PWD to login manually to the DB instance using SQL authentication, so I know the security settings are all correct to allow access to the DB via asp (I presume).

My connection string is:

```
Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=server_name\SQLEXPRESS;Database=qqq;UID=qqq_user;PWD=qqq_password;
```

(I have substituted 'server_name' etc for the true values.)

The error message I get returned from the asp page only occurs when I try to open a recordset, i.e.

```
oRS1.Open.
```

I am declaring all variables etc ... As I said, this code worked perfectly before. The error I'm getting is:

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0e7a'
>
> Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed."

What am I missing? PLEASE help! I have run a search on the above error, but to date, found no solution, as most are quite old solutions, to older versions of SQL Server.

Comment: did you install SQL Native client interface v 10? (SQLNCLI10)

Comment: I've looked in SQL Server Config Manager and it shows there ... Shared Mem, TCP/IP and Named Pipes all set to 'enabled'

Comment: I think native client is up to version 11 now, so try SQLNCLI11.  As a last resort try SQLOLEDB.  See this http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-oledb-provider/ and this http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/

Comment: @john ... THANKYOU!!!!!!! changing "SQLNCLI10" to "SQLNCLI11" did the trick! **YOU STAR!!!!!!** Axarydax - thanks for your input too! :)

Comment: It was an educated guess, but seeing as it worked I'll post it as the answer now.

Answer (score 2):

I think native client is up to version 11 now, so try SQLNCLI11. As a last resort try SQLOLEDB

see http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-11-0-oledb-provider/

and http://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb/